# How to open new html page from axios request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am sending a request to the server which is returning me HTML page, when I made a request through axios in the complete page is in response.data. How should i open this?

```
axios.post("/getEmployee")
    .then(response => {
     if (response.request.responseURL && response.request.responseURL.includes("/login")) {
       window.location.href = response.request.responseURL;
     } 
     else{
             console.log(response.data)
             window.open(response.data)
     }
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data)
    })
```